# mingw, OpenCV 2.4.10 and eclipse C/C++ developer collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: opencv, mingw

`mingw` and `eclipse` is working fine. I tried to setup `OpenCV` and build my project but getting the following errors. I don't have any clue to solve this issue.. I google it but no luck.

```
12:21:54 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project VideoBackGroundRemoval ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IE:\\opencv\\build\\include\\" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\main.o" "..\\src\\main.cpp" 
g++ "-LE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86" -o VideoBackGroundRemoval.exe "src\\main.o" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_flann2410" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_gpu2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_highgui2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_imgproc2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_ml2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_legacy2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_nonfree2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_objdetect2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_ocl2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_photo2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_stitching2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_superres2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_video2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_videostab2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\opencv_ffmpeg2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_ml2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_calib3d2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_contrib2410.dll" "-lE:\\opencv\\minGW\\x86\\bin\\libopencv_core2410.dll" 
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_flann2410
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_gpu2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_highgui2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_imgproc2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_ml2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_legacy2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_nonfree2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_objdetect2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_ocl2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_photo2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_stitching2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_superres2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_video2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_videostab2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\opencv_ffmpeg2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_ml2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_calib3d2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_contrib2410.dll
e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lE:\opencv\minGW\x86\bin\libopencv_core2410.dll
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

12:21:55 Build Finished (took 999ms)
```

Comment: Finally i fixed it. add all libraries without file extension. no need to write libopencv_core2410.dll. Just name of the file is fine "libopencv_core2410" I also document all configuration steps at http://thinkingweb.co/configure-mingw-eclipse-ide-for-cc-developers-and-opencv-2-4-10/

Comment: @Exhausted: please note that inline code spans (`like this`) are only meant to be used for code in sentences, not for highlighting stuff. Also, please try to improve the post as much as possible when editing (as the [editing guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) note). See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text) for more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do your -l... references include full path names to DLL files?  If the path isn't one which the compiler searches automatically, the directory path belongs in a -L... specification, and just the base name, (without extension), of the DLL file belongs in the -l... specification.

Also note that gcc will often add a 'lib' prefix, and '.a', '.lib', or '.dll' suffix, or even a .dll.a suffix, to the name you specify with with -l...; see the heading *direct linking to a dll* at https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/WIN32.html#WIN32, for details of the exact sequence of names for which a MinGW compiler/linker will search.